# Pod updation take too much time and did not get any respone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, terminal, cocoapods

I updated my cocoapod version to 1.0.0.In my podfile containing many libraries and I want update libraries  using **pod repo update** command.After running this command i got the message like this

> Updating spec repo `master` Performing a deep fetch of the `master`
>   specs repo to improve future performance.

Then i did not get any response.Its hanging that message.
I am using terminal in Mac OS X EI Captian version 10.11.1
How to solve this issue? Please help me.

Comment: How many times you wait??

Comment: More than one hour.Then i stopped command execution.

Comment: Why not try only '$ pod update' command

Comment: You want to update all pods ??

Comment: Yes i need to update all pods